# Can I leave Easter side dishes in a closed (off) oven for three hours safely?

Tags: storage-method

I have people coming for Easter dinner immediately after church. I don't have a timer so if I cook the side dishes in the oven, can I leave them there with the oven door closed? Will the be ready to serve 3 hrs. later?

Comment: Do you mean you want to leave the oven off and hope it stays hot enough to be safe? Or that you want to leave it on at a low temperature?

Comment: what are the dishes? Do they normally take three hours to cook? Are you concerned with them staying warm, not drying out, not getting overcooked, not being undercooked, or what? Please edit your question to add more details

Comment: Sorry, but there isn't nearly enough information to even make a stab at this. There is no mention of the types of foods, whether drying, oil-pooling or melting are concerns, or the foods are cooked or uncooked when left in the oven. Please provide additional information.

Comment: I agree with the others, the situation is unclear. If this is a food safety question about a turned off oven, it is a duplicate, see http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/34670 and http://cooking.stackexchange.com/tags/food-safety/info for more background. Else consider adding more detail, then we can reopen the quesiton.